# GraphQLError when sending mutation

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm getting the following Syntax error when trying to use Apollo client

> GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found $

The query i'm sending is like so

```
const CREATE_AUTHOR = gql`
  {
    mutation createAuthor($firstName: String, $lastName: String) {
      createAuthor(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName) {
        firstName
        lastName
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

My type definitions on the server are defined like this

```
//...
  type Mutation {
    createAuthor(firstName: String! lastName: String!): Author
    updateAuthor(_id: String firstName: String lastName: String): Author
    deleteAuthor(_id: String): Author
  }

//...
```

My question is what is in correct with my useage of `gql` looking at the apollo docs

> https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#calling-mutations

Their example matches my implementation I believe or I maybe misunderstanding the usage

```
const ADD_TODO = gql`
  mutation addTodo($type: String!) {
    addTodo(type: $type) {
      id
      type
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: What does your `this.onSubmit` function look like? It looks like this line `this.onSubmit(e, createAuthor, firstName, lastName)` _might_ be the discrepancy...

Comment: @ChrisForrette this is a compile-time error I highly doubt it's related to the onSubmit function as it doesn't have a chance to fire

Comment: @ChrisForrette I can add it if you'd like though

Comment: @ChrisForrette I've updated :)

Comment: Gotcha—I assumed the error was occurring on submit.

Comment: Nah but thanks any way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out—it's a simple one! Don't put brackets around your mutation—it should look like this instead:

```
const CREATE_AUTHOR = gql`
  mutation createAuthor($firstName: String, $lastName: String) {
    createAuthor(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName) {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: bingo! cheers dude big help. I knew it was going to be something along those lines but didn't even think of that good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a comma here: `mutation createAuthor($firstName: String $lastName: String) {`

Should be `mutation createAuthor($firstName: String, $lastName: String) {`

Comment: sorry forgive me if i've missed it but that looks like the exact same

Comment: I added an edit, but check the comma between the `createAuthor` arguments

Comment: yeah i've tried that before but it hasn't worked seen both versions done in tutorials so feel like they may be optional but googling atm to see what the spec is

Comment: Weird, I've never seen that before. The spec is here: https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Language.Arguments

It seems to use commas.

Comment: cheers for the link! yeah i'll be adding them to my querys but unfortionally hasnt resolved the issue but thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may need to send variables to the mutation component, e.g.:

```
<Mutation mutation ={CREATE_AUTHOR} variables={{"firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName}}>
```

**UPDATE**

Although this isn't exactly what you're looking for, here's how I do Apollo mutations at this time.

*A function belonging to the React component class:*

```
sendInstantMsg(createIM) {
    const textToSendElem = document.getElementById("textToSend");
    const textToSend = textToSendElem.value;

    const {toID} = this.props;
    const fromID = Meteor.userId();
    const msgText = trimInput(textToSend);

    createIM({
        variables: {
            "fromID": fromID,
            "toID": toID,
            "msgText": msgText
        },
        optimisticResponse: {
            __typename: 'Mutation',
            createIM: {
                __typename: 'instant_message',
                id: -1, 
                fromID: fromID,
                toID: toID,
                msgText: msgText,
                createdAt: +new Date
            },
        },
        update: (cache, {data: {createIM}}) => {
            let cacheData = cache.readQuery({query: GETIMS_QUERY, variables: {"fromID": fromID, "toID": toID}});
            let instant_message = cacheData.instant_message;
            if (!isDuplicateObject(createIM, instant_message)) {
                instant_message.push(createIM);

                cache.writeQuery({
                    query: GETIMS_QUERY,
                    data: {instant_message},
                    variables: {"fromID": fromID, "toID": toID}
                });
            }
            textToSendElem.value = "";
            scrollToBottomOfTextMsgs();
        }
    })
}
```

*In the render function:*

```
<Mutation
    mutation={CREATE_IM_MUTATION}
>
    {(createIM, {data}) => (
        <RaisedButton
            id="sendMsgButton"
            label="SEND"
            style={styles.makeApptButton}
            secondary={true}
            onClick={() => this.sendInstantMsg(createIM)}
        />
    )}
</Mutation>
```

Comment: would that send the mutation straight away?

Comment: also this is a syntax error with the mutation I think it's just to do with how i've written my query but i maybe mistaken